# ReactiveMongo & JSON4S

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah, reactivemongo, json4s

I'm using JSON4S to parse some JSON strings I'm getting from external APIs.

Is there anyway to get JSON entities like there is with the play reactivemongo JSONCollection or the spray-json to reactive mongo converter in sprest?

Its easy to use JSON4S with the standard Mongo Casbah lib e.g. `builder.insert(JObjectParser.parse(obj))`

But I really want to be able to do this with reactivemongo.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by taking a look at how it's implemented in play-reactivemongo plugin (conversion between play's js reads/writes and reactivemongo's types) [here](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo/blob/master/src/main/scala/play/modules/reactivemongo/json.scala).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this is always the first thing that pops up when I google it.

I've begun working on a project that does this based on the Play Framework's plugin.

Check the issue tracker, because there are currently some problems that may make using it not an option.

https://github.com/Jacoby6000/Json4s-reactivemongo-compatibility